# Bootstrap toggle fails to continue working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I have an issue with Bootstrap toggle menu feature and MVC.
I have my base layout with scripts and menus all fine - but if i use a toggle feature in mobile view it works for the current page once, after that the other pages clicking it nothing happens..

I almost got around it by moving the menu into a partial view and including this on the bottom of every page instead of just being in the main layout, but strangly the issue is then reversed, it works on all pages till I hit F5 - then is stops working again??

Layout:

```
    @{
    ViewData["Logo"] = "bird.png";
    ViewData["Icon"] = "cascade.ico";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="Robots" content="noindex" />
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
    <title>@ViewBag.SiteTitle</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/img/@ViewBag.Icon" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <environment names="Development">
        <!-- Dev uses full file versions for de-bugging -->
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-mobile-min/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-mobile-min/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </environment>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="~/styles/all/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Mobile/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 481px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Desktop/desktop.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px)" />
    <script src="~/app.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Styles/Print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mypage" data-role="page">
        <div id = "header" data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
            <div id="headnav" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div id="headercontainer" class="container">
                    <div style="position:relative; z-index:10" class="pull-left" rel="home" href="#" title="@ViewBag.SiteTitle">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "App")" title="Home">
                            <img style="max-width:100px; max-height: 100px; margin-top: 5px"
                                 src="~/img/@ViewBag.Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar navbar-text" >
                        <h3 class="title">@ViewBag.Title</h3>
                        <h5 class="subtitle">@ViewBag.SubTitle</h5>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Logout Box -->
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Logout")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content -->
        <div id="maincontent" data-role="content" class="container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_NavigationFooter")
    </div>

    <!-- overriding customer styles -->
    <link href="~/styles/customstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Footer Partial:

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
<footer id="pagefooter" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
    <div id="mobilefooterheight" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div id="footercontainer" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer-body">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("MyDetails", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/myrecord.png" />My Record</a></li>
                    <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("MyTeam", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/myteam.png" />Team Headcount</a></li>
                    <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Holidays")"><img src="~/img/icons/holidays.png" />My Holidays</a></li>
                    <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Payslips", "App")"> <img src="~/img/icons/payslips.png" />Payslip</a></li>
                    <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Tasks")"><img src="~/img/icons/tasks.png" />Tasks</a></li>
                    <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Request")"><img src="~/img/icons/authorise.png" />Requests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer-body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @*<ul class="footer-bar-btns visible-xs">
                        <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("MyDetails", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/myrecord.png" />My Record</a></li>
                        <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("MyTeam", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/myteam.png" />Team Headcount</a></li>
                        <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Holidays")"><img src="~/img/icons/holidays.png" />My Holidays</a></li>
                        <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Payslips", "App")"> <img src="~/img/icons/payslips.png" />Payslip</a></li>
                        <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Tasks")"><img src="~/img/icons/tasks.png" />Tasks</a></li>
                        <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Request")"><img src="~/img/icons/authorise.png" />Requests</a></li>
                    </ul>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

In this current form I have put the code back to the footer simply being in the layout all pages use, which is my preference. But can anyone explain why the system would fail to toggle after the first use or when I have navigated to another page in general. F5 corrects it, then using the menu it stops working again on the next page, unless I hit F5.

Im sure its to do with my scripts for bootstrap not loading on the RenderBody or something to that effect but cannot find a fix.

Comment: If this intended to be a question building on top of [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357581/mvc-post-stops-bootstrap-scripts-working), please delete the old one so folks aren't confused.

Comment: Some other javascript error could be causing any javascript on your page to stop working